# How to build wars in <apim-home>/repository/deployment/server/webapps

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed WSO2 API manager4.0.0 All-in-one on the vm.
I found some wars but i don't know where were they from, [image]

Some of the wars could build from carbon-apimgt repo, like api#am#admin, api#am#devportal, api#am#publisher, which could get from carbon-apimgt/components directory by running command "mvn clean install". But I don't know where the other wars build from , like 'api#identity#recovery#v0.9.war'.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find api#identity#recovery#v0.9.war in [1].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/tree/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.endpoint

Comment: Two of webapps were accountrecoveryendpoint and authenticationendpoint, which had no war in the directory , where were they built from ?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/tree/master/apps/recovery-portal

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/tree/master/apps/authentication-portal